# Get method parameter instance in Pointcut implementation

Tags: java, reflection, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

I have one requirement to get the intercepted method's parameter value from pointcut implementation as follows.

Intercepted method :

```
public void execute(Object mapValues)throws Throwable{
....
}
```

and in Aspect Implementation

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(*com.AdhocJob.execute(..))", throwing="ex")
        public void afterThrowing(JoinPoint pjp,Throwable ex) {
           MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
....
}
```

Is it possible to get the instance of "mapValues" parameter in afterThrowing method.
Could someone please put some light on it.

Comment: [JoinPoint.getArgs](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/JoinPoint.html#getArgs()).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getArgs() method from the JoinPoint argument:

```
JoinPoint.getArgs()
```

as in comment by [Boris the spider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider)